# How to generate an array from MagicDraw SysML model?

Tags: uml, code-generation, magic-draw, sysml

I am using MagicDraw 18.0 Enterprise Evaluation version, with the SysML plugin. In the generated code I want to see an array like this:

```
public List<Integer> MyList;
```

So my model contains a property typed Integer, with multiplicity set to *. But that model will simply generate:

```
public Integer MyList;
```

In the model if the type is set Default::List, the only thing possible resembling a List, the generated code from that won't be even valid Java code. This is what's generated:

```
public Default.List MyList;
```

How to set my model for a generated collecction?

Answer (score 0):

This link answered my question: https://community.nomagic.com/associations-and-multiplicity-t158.html
In a nutshell: setting multiplicity is not enough. Java language properties have to be correctly set on every collection.